# Stale state with custom react hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

```js
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
  rootElement
)

function square(n, timeout = 1000) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(n * n), timeout);
  });
}

function App() {
  const [number, setNumber] = React.useState(0);
  const [loading, result, error, reload] = useAsync(
    () => square(number, 1000),
    [number]
  );
  console.log(number, result);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        Decrement{" "}
        <button
          disabled={loading}
          type="button"
          onClick={e => setNumber(number => setNumber(number - 1))}
        >
          -
        </button>
      </div>
      <div>Number: {number}</div>
      <div>Its square: {result} {loading && <span className="fa fa-spinner"></span>}</div>
      <div>
        Increment
        <button
          type="button"
          disabled={loading}
          onClick={e => setNumber(number => setNumber(number + 1))}
        >
          +
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}



function useAsync(func, dependencyArray = []) {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    loading: false,
    result: null,
    error: null,
    mounted: true
  });

  const reload = () => {
    function call() {
        setState(state => ({
          ...state,
          loading: true,
          error: null,
          result: null
        }));
        func()
        .then(res=>{
          if (!state.mounted) return;
          setState(state => ({
            ...state,
            result: res,
            loading: false
          }));
        })
        .catch(err=>{
          setState(state => ({
          ...state,
          loading: false,
          result: null,
          error
        }));
        })        
    }
    call();
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    reload();
    return () =>
      setState({
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        result: null,
        error: null
      });
  }, dependencyArray);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setState(state => ({ ...state, mounted: true }));
    return () => setState(state => ({ ...state, mounted: false }));
  }, []);

  return [state.loading, state.result, state.error, reload, setState];
}
```

```css
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-direction: column;
}

button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

I am using a custom react hook to call APIs and set state in my react component. hook takes a function which returns promise and dependency array. Hook returns `[loading, result, error, reload, setState]`.  I am hoping that result will reset as soon as dependency of hook changes but state remains stale for one render which breaks the logic in component. 
Steps to reproduce.
 I. suppose number is 2 then its square is 4.
 II. Open console.
 III. increment 2, number will become 3, after one second square will come as 9.
 IV. In console you will see something like, **2 4**, **3 4**, **3 null**, **3 9**
 V. **3 4** is buggy log here.

Comment: Thanks for useful links @T.J.Crowder. I have made appropriate modifications.

Answer (score 1):

You are seeing null in the console because whenver the number changes, you are resetting the state inside your custom hook to have `result = null` in the reload function as well as the cleanup function of useEffect

```
const reload = () => {
    async function call() {
      try {
        setState(state => ({
          ...state,
          loading: true,
          error: null,
          result: null
        }));
        const res = await func();
        if (!state.mounted) return;
        setState(state => ({
          ...state,
          result: res,
          loading: false
        }));
      } catch (error) {
        if (!state.mounted) return;
        setState(state => ({
          ...state,
          loading: false,
          result: null,
          error
        }));
      }
    }
    call();
  };
```

If you do not want to reset value to null and only update it once the calculation is complete, you could avoid resetting the values but I will suggest you to continue with what you have done as it handles scenarios better and since you have set the state loading to true anyways you can show the loader till the result is fetched.

However you can remove the setState in cleanup function of useEffect, that isn't needed

```
const reload = () => {
    async function call() {
      try {
        setState(state => ({
          ...state,
          loading: true,
        }));
        const res = await func();
        if (!state.mounted) return;
        setState(state => ({
          ...state,
          result: res,
          loading: false
        }));
      } catch (error) {
        if (!state.mounted) return;
        setState(state => ({
          ...state,
          loading: false,
          result: null,
          error
        }));
      }
    }
    call();
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    reload();
  }, dependencyArray);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer @shubham. but null is totally intentional and not a bug. When my app prints **3 4**, that is bug because 4 is square of 2, which was previous state. I have created working snippet. Please run and see. bug is visible in console only.

Comment: I can't see it printing 3 4 anytime

Comment: when number is set to 2, and you increment it, it will print 3 4. Please increment the number to 2 first. and then increment it once again. you will see 3 4.

Comment: That is because useEffect inside useAsync is only triggered after number is changed so a re-render occurs with incremented number than useEffect is called and state is set to null and then when data is available its set to the correct value. I hope that explains the situation to you

Comment: Let me know if you have doubt still

Comment: Thanks for explaining @shubham. Is there any way I can fix this problem ?

Comment: @gautamits Well, its not really an issue that needs to be fixed but a behaviour with lifecyles in react.

Answer (score 0):

When you click the increment or decrement button multiple times, you have multiple outstanding promises. Then `result` is simply being updated as each promise is resolved.

If your primary concern is making sure the user does not see an incorrect result, you could have the passed function return an array with its original argument as well as the answer, then check to make sure that the current value of `number` matches it:

```
function square(n, timeout = 1000) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve([n, n * n]), timeout);
  });
}

export default function App() {
  const [number, setNumber] = useState(0);
  const [loading, argAndResult, error, reload] = useAsync(
    () => square(number, 1000),
    [number]
  );
  if (argAndResult && argAndResult[0] === number) 
      { result = argAndResult[1]; }
  else { result = null; }
```

Not ideal but would work in certain use cases.

Comment: Issue is not because of multiple outstanding promises @jdaz. I have updated the demo in such a way that, while loading, both buttons will be disabled. therefore no multiple outstanding promises. But you can see that issue is still there.